# D3 and java script

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

Okay i rewrote the code again and this time just passed the parameters for the translate function, but its still not taking the value.

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en" class="tas-com">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Simple Stars</title>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

 <h1>Some Stars</h1>



 <svg width="200" height="200" style='background: aliceblue'>

 </svg>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 var x;
 var y;
 function draw(q,r){
  var svg1 = d3.select("svg");
  svg1.append("polygon")
    .attr("points", "0,0.9511, 1.0,0.95111, 1.309,0, 1.618,0.9511, 2.618,0.9511, 1.809,1.5388, 2.118,2.4899, 1.309,1.9021, 0.5,2.4899, 0.809,1.5388")
     .attr("fill", "blue")
    .attr("transform", "translate(q, r), scale(4)")
    .style("fill", "yellow");
 }
  
  var svg = d3.select("svg");
  svg.append("rect")
     .attr("x", 0)
     .attr("y", 0)
     .attr("width", 200)
     .attr("height", 200)
     .style("fill", "blue");
   
    
   for (var i=0;i<150;i+=15){ 
        var o=30
        draw(o+i,o+i)
   }

   
 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.10/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Hey I'm trying to mess around with d3 and javascript, and was trying to draw the European flag. But the stars are not getting displayed at all. What might be the error? 
I want to use the  function for the x,y coordinates  value to be taken. The circles drawn are just placeholders for the time being.

thanks

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en" class="tas-com">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Simple Stars</title>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

 <h1>Some Stars</h1>

 <svg width="200" height="200" style="background: aliceblue"/>
 </svg>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 var x
 var y
 function draw(q){
  x= 100 + 60*Math.cos(q)
  y= 100 + 60*Math.sin(q)
  return x,y
 }

  var svg = d3.select("svg");
  
  svg.append("rect")
     .attr("x", 0)
     .attr("y", 0)
     .attr("width", 200)
     .attr("height", 200)
     .style("fill", "blue");
    {draw(10) 
    svg.append("polygon")
    .attr("points", "x,y, x+1.0,y, x+1.309,y-0.9511, x+1.618,y, x+2.618,y, x+1.809,y+0.5877, x+2.118,y+1.5388, x+1.309,y+0.951, x+0.5,y+1.5388, x+0.809,y+0.5877")
    .attr("transform", "translate(30, 30), scale(4)")
    .style("fill", "green");
    };
    {draw(25) 
    svg.append("circle")
     .attr("cx", x)
     .attr("cy", y)
     .attr("r", 5)
     .style("fill", "red")
    };
    {draw(40) 
    svg.append("circle")
     .attr("cx", x)
     .attr("cy", y)
     .attr("r", 5)
     .style("fill", "red")
    };
    {draw(55) 
    svg.append("circle")
     .attr("cx", x)
     .attr("cy", y)
     .attr("r", 5)
     .style("fill", "red")
    };
    
    {draw(70) 
    svg.append("circle")
     .attr("cx", x)
     .attr("cy", y)
     .attr("r", 5)
     .style("fill", "red")
    };
    {draw(85) 
    svg.append("circle")
     .attr("cx", x)
     .attr("cy", y)
     .attr("r", 5)
     .style("fill", "red")
    };
    
    {draw(100) 
    svg.append("circle")
     .attr("cx", x)
     .attr("cy", y)
     .attr("r", 5)
     .style("fill", "red")
    };
    {draw(115) 
    svg.append("circle")
     .attr("cx", x)
     .attr("cy", y)
     .attr("r", 5)
     .style("fill", "red")
    };
    {draw(130) 
    svg.append("circle")
     .attr("cx", x)
     .attr("cy", y)
     .attr("r", 5)
     .style("fill", "red")
    };
    {draw(145) 
    svg.append("circle")
     .attr("cx", x)
     .attr("cy", y)
     .attr("r", 5)
     .style("fill", "red")
    };
    {draw(160) 
    svg.append("circle")
     .attr("cx", x)
     .attr("cy", y)
     .attr("r", 5)
     .style("fill", "red")
    };
    {draw(175) 
    svg.append("circle")
     .attr("cx", x)
     .attr("cy", y)
     .attr("r", 5)
     .style("fill", "red")
    };

   
 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: why do you close the svg twice? have you ever considered rewriting your code?

Comment: where are you drawing stars? `sin` and `cos` have radians as arguments, **not** degrees. What do you want to draw at `10`? That will not show anything green. Using global `x` and `y` is **very** bad.

Comment: the stars have to  be drawn at the place of the circles, Initially i drew circles by passing the radians as a parameter and the x,y value are calculated using 
x=a+rcos(rad) y=b+sin(rad), my question is if the code works when it can display the circles why isnt it showing the star ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your refactor is better but this line

```
.attr("transform", "translate(q, r), scale(4)")
```

Should be written as:

```
.attr("transform", "translate(" + q + "," + r + "), scale(4)")
```

Here's the whole code cleaned up a bit more:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="tas-com">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Simple Stars</title>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <h1>Some Stars</h1>

  <svg width="200" height="200" style='background: aliceblue'>

  </svg>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var svg;

    function draw(q, r) {

      var x = 100 + 60 * Math.cos(q),
        y = 100 + 60 * Math.sin(q)

      svg.append("circle")
        .attr("cx", x)
        .attr("cy", y)
        .attr("r", 5)
        .style("fill", "red");

      svg.append("polygon")
        .attr("points", "0,0.9511, 1.0,0.95111, 1.309,0, 1.618,0.9511, 2.618,0.9511, 1.809,1.5388, 2.118,2.4899, 1.309,1.9021, 0.5,2.4899, 0.809,1.5388")
        .attr("fill", "blue")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + (x - 5) + "," + (y - 5) + "), scale(4)")
        .style("fill", "yellow");
    }

    svg = d3.select("svg");

    svg.append("rect")
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("y", 0)
      .attr("width", 200)
      .attr("height", 200)
      .style("fill", "blue");

    for (var i = 0; i < 150; i += 15) {
      var o = 30
      draw(o + i, o + i)
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```